# Intellij-Idea - Tomcat Remote Update

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea

Using Local Tomcat Run/Debug Configuration there is a option to update resources and classes at runtime. However in Remote Tomcat Run configuration there is no such option. Does it mean intellij is unable to update files on remote Tomcat server?

If not what is the actual difference beetween Tomcat Remote and standard Remote Run/Debug configurations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably you don't have any artifact configured in your "Deployment" tab.
Add any and the missing options will appear:

[image]

In "Local" Tomcat configuration, "On 'Update' action" is always visible. However if you don't have configured artifacts for deployment, it will contain "Restart server" only. In "Remote" configuration you don't have the option to restart the server as it runs in different JVM, so the "On 'Update' action" is not visible (I agree this hiding is confusing though).